# Replacing Integers with Strings Java

Tags: java, string, replace, integer

I'm doing a basic Java tutorial and below is the question.

Write a method that prints the numbers from 1 to 100. But for multiples of three print ÒFizzÓ instead of the number,and for the multiples of five print ÒBuzzÓ. For numbers which are multiples of both three and five print ÒFizzBuzzÓ."

My code is below

```
public static void fizzBuzz(){

        for(int i = 0; i < 101; i= i +1 ){
            System.out.println(i);
        if (i%15 == 0){
            System.out.println("ÒFizzBuzzÓ");
        }else if (i % 3 == 0){
            System.out.println("ÒBuzzÓ");
        }else if (i % 5 == 0){
            System.out.println("ÒFizzÓ");
        }

        }
    }
```

It seemingly runs fine, but on closer inspection of the output, the "Fizz" and "Buzz" lines are printed AFTER the relevant numbers and are not printed as a replacement of the numbers

For example, I get the below

```
9
ÒBuzzÓ
10
ÒFizzÓ
11
12
ÒBuzzÓ
13
14
15
ÒFizzBuzzÓ
16
```

How do I get the relevant numbers to be replaced by the correct string statements instead of what I currently have? I only managed to find tips on converting strings to integers, but not replacement of integers to strings on SO, so I would appreciate any help :)

Comment: Only print the number if you aren't printing anything else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move printing of number in else part of your if else ladder as like:

```
for(int i = 1; i < 101; i= i +1 ){
    if (i%15 == 0){
        System.out.println("ÒFizzBuzzÓ");
    }else if (i % 3 == 0){
        System.out.println("ÒBuzzÓ");
    }else if (i % 5 == 0){
        System.out.println("ÒFizzÓ");
    } else {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```